# Metadata extractor: Is the exif tag 'orientation' respected when calculating image width and height?

Tags: metadata-extractor

I want to use the metadata-extractor Java Library version 2.18 to extract metadata from images. Does the library respect the orientation Exif tag on the calculation of the image width and height of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library will provide you access to all three values: width, height, orientation. You can do with them as you wish.

If you think there'd be a generally useful helper function that we could add to the library to make this easier to get right, we would consider a pull request, depending upon the proposed API.

Comment: Hey Drew, thank you for your answer and many thanks for your great work at the metadata-extractor project! This library is very useful.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it's helpful for you. I do think the orientation number we currently produce isn't as helpful as I'd like. While it does enable you to do the right thing, the library should make it easier. Open to suggestions as to how this might work.